# Convergent series proof!

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $S$ be a non-empty subset of $\Bbb{R}$ that is bounded above. Show that there exists a
sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ contained in $S$ (that is, $a_n \in S$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$) which is convergent
with limit equal to $\sup(S)$.

I have no idea how to approach this question, or what it even means. Last question of the problem set. Someone help please!

Comment: Perhaps writing down what "$\alpha=\sup S$" means   will help.

Comment: If you're working on a problem and you don't know what it even means, you need to do some work before asking a question.  What is the first word in the problem that doesn't make sense to you?  Look it up in your textbook.  Can you draw a picture?  What if you chose such a set $S$; can you visualize what $(a_n)$ would be?

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ isn't empty and it's bounded above then $\sup S$ is finite. The characterization of $\sup A$ is:

$$\forall n\in\Bbb N, \exists a_n\in S,\quad S-\frac1n<a_n\le S$$
and the result follows.